# How to check function to see if parent exists

Tags: javascript

Working on a JS function: How would I check to see if a parent element exists and if it doesn't print out 'not found'. Also how do I check for a parent element with a certain className?

```js
var findParentByClassName = function(element, targetClass) {
  if (element) {
    var currentParent = element.parentElement;
    while (currentParent.className !== targetClass && currentParent.className !== null) {
      currentParent = currentParent.parentElement;
    } // closes loop
    return currentParent;
  } // closes if statement
};
```

I was thinking to write this:

```js
if (element.parentElement !== targetClass) {
  console.log('Parent not found');
}
```

Comment: Post code please, what are you working with so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an example of closest() and get() Jquery functions. Of course everything in the DOM has a parent, so we will check for something special, a form with class="myclass":

```
var element = $(yourElement).closest('form.myclass');

if(element.get(0)){
 //you got your element
 }
 else{
  console.log('not found');
 }
```

The method get([index]) is needed due, the selector won't return empty.

Comment: What if I am not allowed to use jQuery functions?

Comment: Then try to check the closest() algorithm, your code seems to be pretty close.

Comment: [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is a standard function but not only for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if immediate parent has certain class, you can do it several ways:

Pure JavaScript (best performance):

```
if (element.parentElement.classList.contains('nameOfClass')) {}
```

jQuery (best jQuery performance):

```
if ($(element).parent().hasClass('nameOfClass')) {}
```

jQuery (usable for every selector, not just class, worse performance):

```
if ($(element).parent('.nameOfClass').length) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function, no external libraries required. Here's an example:

```js
const findParentByClassName = (element, targetClass) => element.closest('.' + targetClass);

const target1 = document.getElementById('target1');
const target2 = document.getElementById('target2');

console.log(findParentByClassName(target1, 'foo'));
console.log(findParentByClassName(target1, 'bar'));
console.log(findParentByClassName(target2, 'foo'));
console.log(findParentByClassName(target2, 'bar'));
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <div>
      <div id="target1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div>
     <div id="target2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(parent.NameFunctio != null)
{
   parent.NameFunctio();
}
```

Comment: What is this? Shouldn't you add an explanation?